# Оператор => в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, операторы, символы

Изучаю JavaScript, в Википедии встретил [пример описания многомерных массивов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

код такой:

```
// Создание двумерного массива чисел: 
var array = [
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], // Первая строка-массив
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], // Вторая
    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]  // Третья
];

// Вывод массива на консоль:
array.forEach((subArray) => {   // Для каждого под-массива,
   subArray.forEach((item) => { // для каждого его элемента,
       console.log(item);       // — вывести этот элемент на консоль.
   });
});
```

Вопрос: что означает оператор **=>** (оператор ли это вообще)?
Читаю Д. Флэнагана "JavaScript. Подробное руководство", в тексте данный оператор не встречается, в сети тоже не смог найти описание.

Comment: [Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: А ясно это лямбда функции в JS

Comment: Типо того, но все же советую почитать о них

Comment: Это стрелочные функции, иногда просто стрелками называют, но стрелка это всё таки это >

Comment: Стрелочные функции. Одна из особенностей нового стандарта ECMAScript 6
https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/213455/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Данный оператор называется стрелочной функцией. Появился с ECMA2015.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Стрелочные функции помогают существенно сократить код, ведь

```
var a = a.map( s => s.length );
```

выглядит куда лучше, чем

```
var a = a.map(function(s){ return s.length } );
```

Стрелочными функциями решают еще одну наболевшую проблему JavaScript: необходимость передавать this в контекст исполнения функции. Каждая функция имеет свой контекст, поэтому приходится либо присваивать `this` переменной:

```
var that = this;
var filter1 = function(){
    // this != that
    return that.visible;
};
```

Либо использовать [`bind`](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind) для привязки контекста:

```
var filter1 = (function(){
        return this.visible;
    }).bind( this );
```

Со стрелочной функцией все значительно проще и компактнее, потому что она не создает свой контекст `this`:

```
var filter1 = () => this.visible;
```

Comment: Получается, меняется синтаксис JS? Посмотрел описания в MDN, правильно ли понимаю, что с помощью стрелочной функции можно опустить традиционную запись ф-ии вида function (s) {return s.length} и написать стрелочную ф-ю как бы от аргумента s => s.length ?

Comment: Да, меняется синтаксис. Соответственно пользователи со старыми браузерами получат невыполнение JS со стрелочными функциями.

Comment: @Romanzhivo, `JS` долго, очень долго сидел в яме безнадёжного отсутствия регулярных обновлений, сейчас, наконец-то, TC39 пообещал выпускать регулярные обновления стандарта, вроде даже каждый год. Это, разумеется, будет менять язык, в лучшую сторону, надеюсь (to read: https://habrahabr.ru/company/Voximplant/blog/279177/ ).

Comment: @Other, наверно, я пока не в полной мере могу осознать ценность этого события и, в частности, введения нового синтаксиса :) Но с обратной совместимостью, кажется, будут проблемы: проверил в IE11, стрелочные ф-ии он считает синтаксической ошибкой)

Comment: @Romanzhivo, это как раз хорошо - браузероклепателям придётся вводить стандарт, иначе рискуют вообще потерять аудиторию. Глядишь - произойдёт чудо и `IE` когда-нибудь начнёт следовать стандарту или вообще отомрёт наконец-то. А сейчас он [IE] хоть и чуть адекватнее стал, но ещё далёк от нормальной поддержки. Решение - транспайлер, обычно.

Comment: @Other, да, возможно) Недавно подумалось, что IE на самом деле в каком-то смысле способствует более строгой практике программирования, поскольку часто оказывается, что именно в IE что-то не работает :)

Comment: @Romanzhivo, не способствует, а тормозит. Сколько раз было - что-то работает везде, а в `IE` - нет; приходилось кучу переписывать под хак просто из-за этого камня на шее веба.

Comment: @Other исправил ответ убрав шероховатости. Предлагаю стереть комментарии, относящиеся к этому.

Comment: @ReinRaus, отлично, если желаете, теперь можно и удалить.

Answer (score 8):

`() => {}` - это стрелочная функция. По сути это аналог обычной анонимной функции (`function() {}`), но с одним **важным отличием**: this в стрелочной функции указывает на контекст, в котором определена данная функция, в то время как в обычной анонимной функции this указывает на "объект перед точкой".

Достаточно сравнить 2 вывода следующего скрипта:

```
let Namespace = {
    a: function() {
        return this;
    },

    b: () => {
        return this;
    },

    c: {
        a: function() {
            return this;
        },

        b: () => {
            return this;
        }
    }
}

console.log(Namespace.a(), Namespace.b());
console.log(Namespace.c.a(), Namespace.c.b());
```

Первый `console.log()` выведет сначала объект `Namespace`, а потом объект `window`. Второй `console.log()` выведет сначала объект `Namespace.c` (тот самый "объект перед точкой"), а затем опять объект `window` (потому как стрелочные функции в обоих случаях определены не внутри какой-то функции, а непосредственно в `window`, даже несмотря на то, что находятся внутри объекта `Namespace` (или `Namespace.c` во втором случае)).

Данное свойство стрелочных функций чрезвычайно полезно при использовании функционального стиля ООП:

```js
function ClassName() {
        function privateMethod() { // *
            console.log(this);
        }
    
        this.publicMethod = function() {
            privateMethod();
        }
    }
    
    let instance = new ClassName();
    instance.publicMethod();
```

сравните с:

```js
function ClassName() {
        let privateMethod = () => { // *
            console.log(this);
        }
    
        this.publicMethod = function() {
            privateMethod();
        }
    }
    
    let instance = new ClassName();
    instance.publicMethod();
```

В первом случае `this` ссылается на глобальный объект `window` (при использовании `"use strict"` `this` вообще будет равен `undefined`, что, в целом, намного логичнее), а во втором - на сам объект `instance` (потому как this будет взят из scope'а уровнем выше (то, чего мы и добиваемся).

Раньше, до стрелочных функций, аналогичного поведения приходилось достигать при помощи "привязки" функции к контексту при помощи `.bind()`, или же при помощи `.call()` и `.apply()` методов, либо при помощи сохранения `this` в отдельную локальную переменную (обычно именуемую `self`) в теле конструктора.

Будет ли влиять стиль нотации на публичные методы? **Нет**. В случае с обычной анонимной функцией `this` будет равен объекту перед точкой (а объект перед точкой - ничто иное как `this`), а в случае со стрелочной функцией `this` возьмется из scope'а уровнем выше, в котором он и есть необходимый нам объект.

---

Что касается слова "лямбда", то, как мне кажется, называть так стрелочные функции (в частности) *неверно*, потому как лямбдой принято называть любую анонимную функцию (а, как я указал выше, анонимной функцией может быть не только стрелочная функция).

Comment: что значит _функциональный стиль ооп_?

Comment: @Grundy не прототипный. Не знаю, насколько (не)официально это название.

Comment: В принципе из ответа можно убрать все, кроме первого абзаца, дальше что-то совсем странное начинается. Про потерю контекста, есть отдельный вопрос/ответ, в котором рассмотрены в том числе и стрелочные функции и лучше было сослаться на него.

Comment: @Grundy пускай будет. На нем неплохо разница видна, в качестве примера - почему бы и нет?

Comment: Про `this` не совсем корректно написано - у стрелочных функций просто нет своего this, этим всё сказано. Поэтому при вызове `this` возьмётся на правах переменной - с уровня выше, если где-то определено. Но комент хороший - умозаключение про приватные функции полезно, только не в тему)

Comment: на самом деле пример плохой: много тяжелого текста, код, который не запустить. Как минимум стоит сделать сниппет, вместо просто блока кода

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр "если где-то определено" определен this?

Comment: @smellyshovel ну полностью логика переменной работает: нету в локальном неймспейсе - ищем выше, пока не дойдём до корня. Может не быть конечно this - если JS интерпретируется не в web-странице.

Comment: @Grundy сделал сниппеты

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр логика переменной - да. Но фраза "определен this" сделала мне больно, уж простите. И да, именно из-за слова определен.

Comment: _сделал сниппеты_ - о, нет! теперь одинакового кода в два раза больше :-D

Comment: @Grundy да ладно вам... В целом-то все по-делу написано. Пусть и сложновато для понимания.

Answer (score 7):

Это новый (`ECMAScript2015`) вид записи функций.
Читаем описание [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), спецификацию [тут](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions), гуглением находим кучу примеров для изучения [так](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8+javascript), например [это](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function).

---

Если кратко, то это, конечно, меньше букаф писать, не имеет своего `this`, `arguments` и ещё чего-то. Идеальны для `callback`, мучения с замыканием из-за потери контекста в прошлом. Пример работы уже у Вас есть, приводить не буду.

Answer (score 4):

Это стрелочная функция https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Вот еще немного информации [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190439/is-there-a-c-like-lambda-syntax-in-javascript)

```
// Basic syntax:
(param1, param2, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one argument:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }

// A function with no arguments requires parentheses:
() => { statements }

// Advanced:
// Parenthesize the body to return an object literal expression:
params => ({foo: bar})

// Rest parameters are supported
(param1, param2, ...rest) => { statements }
```