# Какая разница между функцией в переменной и функцией

Tags: javascript

К примеру есть такой код. Какая разница между этими подходами?

```
const func = () =>{
   someting
}
```

```
function func(){
   something other
}
```

Comment: learn.javascript.ru: [1](https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics), [2](https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions), + [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: [Оператор `=>` в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528707).

Comment: Тут дело не только в стрелочной функции, но и в const, а также function declaration и function expression... В целом тут минимум три отличия, три подхода....о каком речь?

Comment: я не javascript-разработчик, но, по-моему, в первом случае, во-первых, лямбда выражении (просто альтернативный вид записи функции (...) => ...), но это не суть, а во-вторых, это ссылка на функцию. Во втором же случае сама функция.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname